# MouseDown event doesn't fire if MouseLeave event exists

Tags: wpf, xaml, events

I have a custom button that I want to add animations to, but when I add the MouseLeave event and click the button while testing it fires the MouseLeave event instead of the MouseDown. When I remove the MouseLeave event it goes back to normal and fires the MouseDown event like expected.

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="CustomButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="4" Background="Green">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Border.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseDown">
                                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                                To="Red" 
                                                Duration="0:0:0.15" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger.Actions>
                            </EventTrigger>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
                                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                                To="Blue" 
                                                Duration="0:0:0.15" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger.Actions>
                            </EventTrigger>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseLeave">
                                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                                To="Green" 
                                                Duration="0:0:0.15" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger.Actions>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Border.Triggers>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I have no idea why this happens so please help

Answer (score 4):

You should handle the tunneling *"Preview..."* events where possible. In your case, handle the `PreviewMouseDown` event.

You should generally try to avoid event triggers to animate control states (or transitions to states). The recommended approach is to [use the `VisualStateManager` to manage states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/creating-a-control-that-has-a-customizable-appearance?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#use-the-visualstatemanager-to-manage-states).
Visit [Microsoft Docs: Control Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/control-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#in-this-section) to learn about the defined states of every library control.

Your Style that uses the [VisualStateManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.visualstatemanager?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) to animate control state transitions (notice the cleaner look):

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border x:Name="Border"
                CornerRadius="4"
                Background="Green">
                
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">  
              <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition From="MouseOver"
                                  To="Normal"
                                  GeneratedDuration="0:0:1.5" />
              </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>

              <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
              <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                  To="Blue"
                                  Duration="0:0:0.15" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                  To="Red"
                                  Duration="0:0:0.15" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                
          <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. It doesn't have an animation when you leave the mouse but that can easily be fixed when you add a storyboard in the Normal visual state.

Comment: Simply define a `VisualTransition`. It controls the transition between your handled states. I have updated the example to show to define the transition between the `MouseOver` and `Normal` state animations.

Comment: Defining an animation for the `Normal` state will also work, of course. Just understand that this animation will always apply when transitioning from any state. `VisualTransition` gives you extra control to differentiate between states. For example it allows to define a different animation when transitioning from `MouseOver` to `Normal` and `Pressed` to `MouseOver`.

Comment: [`VisualTransition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.visualtransition?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#examples) can define animations too.